# Query to join 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query to join 3 tables.

My tables are:

ucommerce_customer

ucommerce_order

ucommerce_order_line

All 3 tables have a column called order_id.

The table ucommerce_order has a column called order_status.

When the order_status is set to "open" I want to display the order details.

```
ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery
("SELECT * FROM ucommerce_customer 
INNER JOIN ucommerce_order 
INNER JOIN ucommerce_order_line 
WHERE ucommerce_order.order_status = 'open'");
```

My query ignores the order status and displays all orders, open and closed.

Also I have several products so ucommerce_order_line has several entries for the same order_id, my query displays duplicate entries and it duplicates the entire list as well.

How can I write a query that will show only open orders without duplicating everything?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html and read the part dealing with `JOIN ... ON ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, the `on`/`using` clause is optional.  This is very sad because someone can make mistakes like you did.  Your question only mentions one column, so perhaps that is all that is needed for the `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ucommerce_customer INNER JOIN
     ucommerce_order 
     USING (orderId) INNER JOIN
     ucommerce_order_line 
     USING (OrderId)
WHERE ucommerce_order.order_status = 'open';
```

I would be surprised if the customer table really had a column called `OrderId` (seems like a bad idea in most situations), so the first `USING` clause might want to use `CustomerId`.

Comment: I set the table ucommerce_customer up to auto increment order_id. When I setup the database I made these 3 tables just for orders. I re-write the customer information from the customer table. I tried your query and it's almost there. I'm getting a repeat of all information for every entry in the ucommerce_order_line table.

Comment: @DaleWahl . . . That is how SQL works.  It repeats all the information on each row.  You should also replace `SELECT *` with the columns that you really need.

Comment: Is there anyway to isolate ucommerce_order_line so that the other tables won't repeat their information for every entry in ucommerce_order_line? I use order_id for every item in ucommerce_order_line, so order id # 244 may be in ucommerce 5 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a natural join instead. Maybe that's where the errors are coming from.

The duplicates can be removed by running `SELECT DISTINCT * ...`

Comment: DISTINCT does nothing when I run it in my query. It seems to ignore it just like it ignore's my WHERE command. My query actually replicates the items displayed 18 times.

Comment: Could you provide some data, or a running sample?

Comment: `natural join` is extremely dangerous and should be avoided.